# Jetpack Compose function with lambda () -> Unit

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda, android-jetpack-compose, modifier

I'm trying to extract a method applied on a modifier into a Composable function

```
 TopAppBar(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.TopCenter)
                .height(56.dp)
                .background(
                    brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
                        colorGradient
                    )
                )
```

Specifically the Brush.verticalGradient() so that I can use the gradient Composable everywhere I need and just pass the list of colors to it.

I know that I need to use a lambda expression inside the Composable function but I'm not sure how to do it.

```
@Composable
private fun BottomBarGradient(
    content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
}
```

I'm pretty new in Compose. Can anyone point out a good tutorial/example for this?

Comment: You do not need any lambdas here, if you want to use same gradient in diferent composables, just decrare it as val myBrush = Brush.verticalGradient(listOf(<your colors goes here>)) somewhere outside of composables and then use it anywhere. .background(brush = myBrush)

Comment: But what if I want to use it inside other compose activities, wouldn't it have made more sense to make is as a composable function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right way. But for you case, while working with TopAppBar/BottomAppBar, you need to apply RowScope (ex. `content: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit`) for more information see [function literal with receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver). I cannot tell were you can find specific information for you case but most can be found in [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/documentation) or [jetpack compose samples](https://github.com/android/compose-samples), for tutorial you can check [google codelabs](https://developer.android.com/courses/pathways/compose)

Your custom composable should look like this:

```
val availableColors = listOf(
    Color.Black, Color.DarkGray,
    Color.Gray, Color.LightGray,
    Color.White, Color.Red,
    Color.Green, Color.Blue,
    Color.Yellow, Color.Cyan,
    Color.Magenta, Color.Transparent
)

@Composable
fun BottomBarVerticalGradient(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit,
) {
    BottomAppBar(
        modifier = modifier.background(Brush.verticalGradient(colors = availableColors)),
        content = content,
        backgroundColor = Color.Transparent
    )
}
```

or more custom way:

```
@Composable
fun BottomBarVerticalGradient(
    colors: List<Color>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    startY: Float = 0f,
    endY: Float = Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY,
    tileMode: TileMode = TileMode.Clamp,
    shape: Shape = RectangleShape,
    alpha: Float = 1.0f,
    content: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit,
) {
    BottomAppBar(
        modifier = modifier.background(
            brush = Brush.verticalGradient(colors = colors, startY, endY, tileMode),
            shape = shape,
            alpha = alpha
        ),
        content = content,
        backgroundColor = Color.Transparent
    )
}
```

or this:

```
@Composable
fun BottomBarVerticalGradient(
    vararg colorStops: Pair<Float, Color>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    startY: Float = 0f,
    endY: Float = Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY,
    tileMode: TileMode = TileMode.Clamp,
    shape: Shape = RectangleShape,
    alpha: Float = 1.0f,
    content: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit,
) {
    BottomAppBar(
        modifier = modifier.background(
            brush = Brush.verticalGradient(colorStops = colorStops, startY, endY, tileMode),
            shape = shape,
            alpha = alpha
        ),
        content = content,
        backgroundColor = Color.Transparent
    )
}
```

Usage:

```
//Scaffold too should be more customizable (ex. modifier, scaffoldState)
@Composable
fun MySuperScaffold() {
    val colorsState = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(availableColors) }

    val shuffle: () -> Unit = {
        colorsState.value = availableColors.shuffled()
    }

    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            BottomBarVerticalGradient(
                modifier = Modifier.height(56.dp).fillMaxWidth(),
                colors = colorsState.value
            ) {
                /* Your bottom bar content */
            }
        },
        content = { Button(onClick = shuffle) { Text("Shuffle") } },
    )
}
```

Comment: This looks like what I've been looking for. I'm a bit busy now but will have to test it and get back to you :) thanks

Comment: Thanks for the multiple examples. This is exactly what I've been looking for. Also for providing the reading materials. It helped me understand better. Have a nice day :)

Comment: @Saul You are welcome. Hope that the documentation answers many of you questions.